# Is it necessary to use an end tag with <div> for clearing floats?

Tags: html, css, css-float

When using a DIV element with a style of **clear:both** to clear a previous float, is it necessary to use a start **and** end tag to the DIV element? Here is an example ...

Is this OK?

```
<div style="clear:both;" />
```

or should it be this?

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: I would assume it would be necessary. It's important to terminate your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the closing tag, or browsers [will not think the tag is closed](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/t66XF/).

However, why would you even want to use `<div style="clear:both;"></div>`? That involves adding an extra unsemantic `div` for no reason.

There are better ways to contain/clear floats:

- Use `overflow: hidden` on the the element that contains your floats.
- Or, use a clearfix such as the ["micro clearfix"](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Comment: Both will work but `overflow: hidden` will become a pain in the arm for grids and such. That's why grid usually come with said microfix, which works wonders.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in XHTML it is OK to use the `<div />`, if you're working in HTML 4.X you should add the `</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Its not valid in HTML 4 & also in HTML5. Valid in XHTML. May chances of intercepting wrongly by browsers.